# Azure Data Lake store create folder via C# script

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to create new folder inside my `datalake store`, there is no error in code however nothing is being reflected in `datalake store`.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
namespace test_dlstore
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient _adlsClient;
        private static DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient;

        private static string _adlsAccountName;
        private static string _subId;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _adlsAccountName = "mycreds@mysite.com"; 

            _subId = "2342342-97ce-a54b2-ba6e-234234234234234";

            string localFolderPath = @"C:\myfolder\"; // TODO: Make sure this exists and can be overwritten.
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localFolderPath, "try.txt");
            string remoteFolderPath = "adl://mystore.azuredatalakestore.net/myfolder";
            string remoteFilePath = Path.Combine(remoteFolderPath, "try.txt");

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            var tenant_id = "my-tenant-id"; 
            var nativeClientApp_clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";


            var activeDirectoryClientSettings = ActiveDirectoryClientSettings.UsePromptOnly(nativeClientApp_clientId, new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
            var creds = UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(tenant_id, activeDirectoryClientSettings).Result;

            _adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = _subId };
            _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
            Console.WriteLine(ListAdlStoreAccounts());
            Console.WriteLine(AppendToFile("adl://mystore.azuredatalakestore.net/myfolder/stage/testfile.txt", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
            CreateDirectory("adl://mystore.azuredatalakestore.net/myfolder/newdir");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        // Append to file
        public static string AppendToFile(string path, string content)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_adlsAccountName, path, content);
                Console.WriteLine(path);
                Console.WriteLine(content);
                _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.AppendAsync(_adlsAccountName, path, stream);
                return "Tried";
            }
        }
        public static string CreateDirectory(string path)
        {
            _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.MkdirsAsync(_adlsAccountName, path);
            return "Tried Creating directory.";
        }
}
}
```

After execution of above code, program exits with no error. The connection is being made.

Also it is displaying `datalake` stores that are present but not able to do anything at all over the data lake stores.

I am new to azure please help me out.

Comment: If you just try to create folder, please have a try to use   `_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Mkdirs(_adlsAccountName, "/folderName")`;

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT Tried it. but **no changes** on my datalake store.

Comment: Please have a try just to use the code I mentioned without other code .Please use 
relative path not full path. I tested on my side it works correctly.

Comment: I got this error on trying:
`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)`

Comment: I have added  more detail steps as an answer, please refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a demo test on my side,it works correctly on side. The following is my detail steps:

**Preparation:**

Registry an AD application and **assign role to applcation**, more details please
refer to [Azure official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). After that we can get **tenantId**, **appId**, **secretKey** from the Azure Portal.

**Steps:**

1.Create an C# console project

2.Referece the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader) SDK, more details please refer to packages.config file section.

3.Add the follow code

```
 var applicationId = "appid";
 var secretKey = "secretkey";
 var tenantId = "tenantid";
 var adlsAccountName = "adlsAccount Name";
 var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
 var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds,clientTimeoutInMinutes:60); 
 adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Mkdirs(adlsAccountName, "/tomtest/newfolder");
```

4.Run the test code

[image]

5.Check from the azure portal.

[image]

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.2-beta1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks. This Worked. I was stuck on this problem since yesterday.